Connect to HSQLDB running on Tomcat Server
I have a web service application that includes code to start HSQLDB when the application is loaded into the database. Everything within the application functions as expected, including connecting to the database, executing procedures, creating tables, and running queries without any issues. However, I am trying to write a separate application to connect to the same database and retrieve data, but I am unable to establish a connection. I have gone through the documentation, but I either do not understand it fully or am overlooking something.
WEBSERVICE APPLICATION CODE AS BELOW:
FILE : HSQLServer.java (Contains code to initialize HSQL SERVER)
    private HsqlServer() {
        //initialze new server
        hsqlServer = new Server();

        hsqlServer.setLogWriter(null);
        hsqlServer.setSilent(true);

        // can use custom writer
        hsqlServer.setLogWriter(null); 
        hsqlServer.setErrWriter(null); 
    }

public void startServer(String dbName, String dbPath) {  
        try {
            HsqlProperties p = new HsqlProperties();

            //dbName: "hsqldb" dbPath: "file:/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/TicketingAPIWS/DB/hsqldb"
            p.setProperty("server.database.0", "file:" + dbPath);
            p.setProperty("server.dbname.0", dbName);

            //set properties for DB
            hsqlServer.setProperties(p);

            //start the database!
            hsqlServer.start();

            LogUtils.log(CustomLogger.LogType.DEBUG, Boolean.TRUE, String.format("startServer:HSQL Database Server Has been Started"));
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            LogUtils.logException(CustomLogger.LogType.SEVERE, Boolean.TRUE, "startServer:Exception due to", ex);
        }
    }

FILE : ITS CALLED FROM LISTENER IN THE MAIN WS APPLICATION: Which starts the HSQLDB and creates and connection to execute Stored procedures which works ALL GOOD
public static void initDB(ServletContext sc) {
        Connection conn = null;
        
        ConfigMgr configMgr = new ConfigMgr(sc);
        LogUtils.setupConfigurationMgr(configMgr);

        try {           
            boolean serverStatus = startHsqlServer(getDBName(configMgr), getDBPath(configMgr));           
            LogUtils.log(CustomLogger.LogType.DEBUG, Boolean.TRUE, String.format("initDB: Hsql Server Status=[%s]",serverStatus));
            
            //check if Hsql server is running
            if(serverStatus) {
                //get connection from the connection pool
                conn = getDefaultDatabaseConnection(configMgr);

                //add today's date as newDay in system_config
                addToSysConfig(conn, "newDay", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
            }

                LogUtils.log(CustomLogger.LogType.DEBUG, Boolean.TRUE, "initDB: Successfully initialized the database");
            } else {
                LogUtils.log(CustomLogger.LogType.SEVERE, Boolean.TRUE, "initDB: Failed to initialize the database");
            }
        } catch(Exception ex){
            LogUtils.logException(CustomLogger.LogType.SEVERE, Boolean.TRUE, "initDB: Exception due to", ex);
        } finally {
            closeConnections(conn);
        } 
    }

This is my CONNECTION STRING: url="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/hsqldb;file:/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/TicketingAPIWS/DB/hsqldb"
EXTERNAL JAVA ANT APP
NOW I have the DB server running. So i am trying to access the HSQLDB from an external app that i wrote like below:
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn1 = null;
        // Display versions
        //clntObj.displayAppVersion(args);
            
        try {
            
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");    
            //jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/pgmcdb
            //conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/hsqldb;file:/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/TicketingAPIWS/DB/hsqldb;server.remote_open=true;", "SA", "");
            conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/TicketingAPIWS/DB/hsqldb;server.remote_open=true;", "sa", "");

            System.out.println(conn1);
            Statement s = conn1.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery ("SELECT web_client_id FROM client_sign_on;");
            
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Table_Name: " + rs.getString(1) );
            }
            
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HsqlClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HsqlClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if(conn1 != null){
                try {
                    conn1.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(HsqlClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

gives this error :
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: client_sign_on
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at hsqlclient.HsqlClient.main(HsqlClient.java:173)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: client_sign_on
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more

The tables exist and are correctly named. I have one record in the database, and I can access it using an SQL tool, where everything appears to be in order. However, I am unable to access the database from outside the web service application, and I cannot find any resources explaining how to do this.
here is the table and it's contents:

The tables exist and are correctly named Please prove that

Also you need to check the grants of privilege to run that query

@g00se For reference, I have included a link to an image showing the table and its contents.

I have not made any changes to the default permissions. If there are specific steps I need to take to grant access, please let me know. @g00se


Are you using the same username and password as in the connection made in the console?
Are you connecting from the same host in each case?


Yes, I am using the same username and password, but I am trying to connect from a different host. This is a remote connection attempt.

Unfortunately I don't know enough about HSQLDB to know for sure whether the second point is a problem or not. It would be in MySql. Let's flag it as a potential one

Once the server has started via Tomcat, the log message should show the HSQL server has been started. You code shows you have chosen the URL name hsqldb for this database.
Now you can connect to the server from outside Tomcat with this URL:
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/hsqldb

Please note once you have started a server with a given database, you can only access the database via the server and no direct access is allowed via a jdbc:hsqldb:file/... connection.
